Wordpress theme mods not stored in WP_Options table, or anywhere else searched and extensively researched
I'm working with an Wordpress theme that's not longer supported, but does most of what's needed.  Unfortunately, it can't be published without changing content that are not found on any Wordpress page or post, and is not in the template customizer.
In general, if I understand correctly, another place to look is in the WP-options table.  Not found there, in this case.  There are only the 25 rows that appear standard with every Wordpress.
For example, in functions.php, there's references to content below, "BUSINESS-OUTSOURCE-URL" that's dynamically displayed, but searching every table using phpMyAdmin, it's nowhere to be found.
/* Footer reference link */
function visit_our_sponsor_link() {
echo esc_html_e('Please visit our sponsor and affiliated sites at','wordpress-template-outsource'). " You will be glad you did!";
I've tried a number of plug-ins that are capable of changing mods, but none has worked.
Can anyone help me understand where else they could be storing this content?
Thank you in advance!
I have searched every php source file within the template, all Wordpress pages and posts, and the included "Template Customizer."  Also, I've searched the Wordpress database, starting with WP-options table, and then searching every other table.
These are the resources I've studied, trying to understand how this works:
Documentation I've referenced:
https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/options/
https://tommcfarlin.com/wordpress-options/
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/202847/where-is-customizer-related-data-stored-is-the-database
https://solidwp.com/blog/wordpress-database-explained/

You are trying to change the text output from my understanding in visit_our_sponsor_link function ? You have few ways of doing this - if its translating, there should be pot file of the theme which you can use to translate. If its simply replacing the string then add child theme and replace the function with your own. Or since its no longer supported you  can work within the parent theme.
